# Update stored procedure from vb.net with multiple lines

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am developing a stored procedure which uses an integer as a key along with several other variables to execute custom sql logic. I want to be able to create new sections of this procedure dynamically so that people with knowledge of sql can add new custom logic without using sql management studio to create it.

Below is my method. Unfortunately I am not able to get multiple lines to apply as multiple lines when executing the sql statement. Since there are comments in the procedure, this doesn't work. I have tried using a SqlCommand object, but that didn't work either. I also tried Chr(6) + Chr(10) (I think those were the right Chrs) but that just came through as text to sql.

```
Public Sub UpdateLogicQueryDefinition(CampaignID As Integer, CalcID As Integer, CalcObjectName As String, AppendedText() As String)
    Dim dr As DataRow, FinalQuery As String = "", SingleLine As String = ""
    Dim NextLine As String = Environment.NewLine
    For Each dr In ds_ExistingLogic.Tables(0).Rows
        FinalQuery = FinalQuery & dr("Text") & NextLine
        If dr("Text").Trim() = "--Insertion point 1" Then
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & " IF @CustomLogicNumber = " & CalcID & NextLine
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & " BEGIN " & NextLine
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & " Goto " & CampaignID & "_" & CalcObjectName & NextLine
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & " END " & NextLine
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & NextLine
        End If
        If dr("Text").Trim() = "--Insertion point 2" Then
            FinalQuery = " " & FinalQuery & CampaignID & "_" & CalcObjectName & ":" & NextLine
            For Each SingleLine In AppendedText
                FinalQuery = FinalQuery & SingleLine & NextLine
            Next
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & " Return " & NextLine
            FinalQuery = FinalQuery & NextLine
        End If
    Next



    FinalQuery.Replace("CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCustomLogic]", "ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCustomLogic]")


    db.ExecuteNonQuery(FinalQuery)
```

Does anyone know how I can get this query to recognize multiple lines so I can update this procedure dynamically? Thanks

Edit: The comments have led me to abandon this approach. I will be using two procedures so I can edit my procedure with sql instead of in code. Thanks

Comment: Char 6 and 10 are not correct for line breaks if that is the question. Char 10 (NL/LF) and 13 (CR) are the ones you want, I think. Or `environment.newline` should do the same if I'm not mistaken. But why not just build dynamic SQL to create the sproc if this is the requirement? That seems easier than doing it in code. OR why not just use 2 sprocs instead of trying to have a single method to dynamically update both? I think this approach is probably the most difficult way I could think to do this.

Comment: "so that people with knowledge of sql can add new custom logic without using sql management studio"???? If they have knowledge of sql why not let them create a procedure instead of this? Writing code to allow customization of procedures is a nightmare. I can only imagine trying to debug one of those things. And goto??

Comment: Thanks @JacobH, using two procedures does seem better.